# Find percentiles of values from distributions of categories in PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have the following PySpark dataframe (say `df`). It has the columns `name`, `timestamp`, `category` and `value`.

```
+------+-------------------+--------+-----+
|  name|          timestamp|category|value|
+------+-------------------+--------+-----+
| name1|2019-01-17 00:00:00|       A|11.23|
| name2|2019-01-17 00:00:00|       A|14.57|
| name3|2019-01-10 00:00:00|       B| 2.21|
| name4|2019-01-10 00:00:00|       B| 8.76|
| name5|2019-01-17 00:00:00|       A|18.71|
| name6|2019-01-10 00:00:00|       A|17.78|
| name7|2019-01-10 00:00:00|       A| 5.52|
| name8|2019-01-10 00:00:00|       A| 9.91|
| name9|2019-01-17 00:00:00|       B| 1.16|
|name10|2019-01-17 00:00:00|       B| 12.0|
+------+-------------------+--------+-----+
```

I want to add a new column to the above mentioned dataframe which gives me the **percentile standings of the values of each name** in distributions which include members of the same `category` and `timestamp`.

My expected output is the following:

```
+------+-------------------+--------+-----+---------+
|name  |timestamp          |category|value|pct_value|
+------+-------------------+--------+-----+---------+
|name1 |2019-01-17 00:00:00|A       |11.23|1        |
|name10|2019-01-17 00:00:00|B       |12.0 |2        |
|name2 |2019-01-17 00:00:00|A       |14.57|2        |
|name3 |2019-01-10 00:00:00|B       |2.21 |1        |
|name4 |2019-01-10 00:00:00|B       |8.76 |2        |
+------+-------------------+--------+-----+---------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

**What is the best way to do this?**

I have tried the following:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

w_cat = W.partitionBy('category', 'timestamp').orderBy("value")

df_new = ( df.select( '*', F.ntile(1000).over(w_cat).alias( 'pct_value' ) ) ).persist()


df_new.orderBy('name', 'timestamp').show(5,False)
```

This gives the correct expected output. But, this method takes a very long time (hours) when I try that on my actual data which has millions of rows.

You can generate the dataframe given above (`df`) using the below mentioned code:

```
Stats = Row("name", "timestamp", "category", "value")

stat1 = Stats('name1', "2019-01-17 00:00:00", "A", 11.23)
stat2 = Stats('name2', "2019-01-17 00:00:00", "A", 14.57)
stat3 = Stats('name3', "2019-01-10 00:00:00", "B", 2.21)
stat4 = Stats('name4', "2019-01-10 00:00:00", "B", 8.76)
stat5 = Stats('name5', "2019-01-17 00:00:00", "A", 18.71)
stat6 = Stats('name6', "2019-01-10 00:00:00", "A", 17.78)
stat7 = Stats('name7', "2019-01-10 00:00:00", "A", 5.52)
stat8 = Stats('name8', "2019-01-10 00:00:00", "A", 9.91)
stat9 = Stats('name9', "2019-01-17 00:00:00", "B", 1.16)
stat10 = Stats('name10', "2019-01-17 00:00:00", "B", 12.0)

stat_lst = [stat1 , stat2, stat3, stat4, stat5, stat6, stat7, stat8, stat9, stat10]
df = spark.createDataFrame(stat_lst)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to `percentile_approx` function.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

grp_window = Window.partitionBy('name')
# For median, i.e. 0.5 quantile
magic_percentile = F.expr('percentile_approx(val, 0.5)')

df.withColumn('pct_value', magic_percentile.over(grp_window))
# OR 
df.groupBy('name').agg(magic_percentile.alias('pct_value'))
```

You can used `percent_rank` function as well:

```
df.select('pct_value', percent_rank().over(w).alias("percentile"))\
    .where('percentile == 0.6').show()
```

You can also pass an array of percentiles, but the catch here is that you will get a `list` in return:

```
quantiles = F.expr('percentile_approx(val, array(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))')
```